# SharedPreferences and Rotation

Tags: android, orientation, sharedpreferences

I have a button in my Apps menu, by clicking on that button the will rotate.. BUT when I close the App and reopen the App its not rotated as I did left it.

I want to **store and retrieve** the **Orientation** with **SharedPreferences**.
I have tried many examples but non of them actually helped me.

Here is my menu code:

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    /** Rotation */
    case R.id.menuRotate:
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if (preferences.getBoolean("orientation", true)) {
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            }
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I have nothing in my onCreate:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
```

Thanks a lot guys in Advance

Comment: Where is your code to save the orientation?

Comment: In the menuRotate you should SAVE the orientation (before or after applying it) and in onCreate you should LOAD it (and apply it accordingly).

Comment: I don't know how to do it ... that's why I am asking! I know how to do it with strings ....I did it in onPause like this...String ipe = InputPrice.getText().toString();
  String ipt = InputPercent.getText().toString();
  Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
  editor.putString(Price, ipe);

Comment: This is from my other app ... I did it to store and retrieve edittext value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case R.id.menuRotate:
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
             .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        editor.putInt("orientation", ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        editor.putInt("orientation", ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
    editor.commit();
    break;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
             .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int orientation = preferences.getInt("orientation", -1);
    if(orientation != -1){
        setRequestedOrientation(orientation);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.